# How to flush retrieved database values from form

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I have been able to retrieve values into my form.The values are inserted into a table on save button click and are at the same time retrieved onto the same form too(on the same save click).But the problem now is that on each click the values are getting displayed in a continuous flow.I want to clear the screen(flush the values from form) after the previous click and display only the latest table state values.
Heres the code i am working on:

```
   public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) //respond to button events
        {

            if (field == showInputButton) //if first button selected
            { 
                Dialog.alert(TextField1.getText()); //show text from first input field  

                try
                {    
                    //Open or create the database
                    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("database1.db");    

                    //Insert Data from db
                    Statement statement1 = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO DirectoryItems(category_id,name,phone,email) VALUES ('1','"+TextField1.getText()+"','"+TextField2.getText()+"','"+TextField3.getText()+"')");
                    statement1.prepare();
                    statement1.execute();       
                    statement1.close(); 
                  //Retrieve data
                    try
                    {
                            add(new RichTextField("Attempting to retrieve data from " + 
                                                                                        "database1.db on the SDCard."));


                            Statement st = db.createStatement("SELECT name FROM DirectoryItems");

                            st.prepare();


                            Cursor c = st.getCursor();

                            Row r;
                            int i = 0;

                            while(c.next()) 
                            {
                                        r = c.getRow();
                                        i++;
                                       add(new RichTextField(i + "Name = " + r.getString(0)));
                            }
                            if (i==0)
                            {
                                        add(new RichTextField("No data in the DirectoryItems table."));
                            }
                            st.close();
                            db.close();
                     }
                     catch( Exception e ) 
                    {         
                        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                  }
```

Does anyone know this.Please advise guys.

Comment: It sounds for me that you need to read more about BB development, UI fields, UI cycle. Also looking to the code example I would suggest you to read more about "clean code" technique

Comment: I sure am a newbie in bb development.Would much appreciate if u cud provide suitable links to aid ur suggestions.

Comment: Does anyone know to solve the above doubt.PLz help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead by disabling buttons so that you allow the user to fetch the values only once (i.e the latest values)

```
 ((ButtonField)showInputButton).setEnabled(false);
```

Use that in your implementation of field change.Disabling buttons helps retain a good grip over the fetched values(as in your case).

Comment: Thank you so much.It never struck me to use disabling of buttons.I have now used the save button field changed event in my search field changed implementation.It works like a charm.Thanks again.